# Save operation lasts too long in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2015

While working on visual studio 2015 update 3, ctrl-s operation lasts 3-4 minutes time to time.

Comment: Are you using a TFS TFVC local workspace? Is that workspace very, very large or on a slow (network) disk?

Comment: No, it is not local workspace and it is not network problem either. Not all the developers get this problem at the same time. Now i struggle with slowness and another developer works easily on the same project, same TFVC, same domain.

Comment: Most likely culprits in that case: Virus scanner, Proxy server, Firewall, bad network connection, slow TFS server, corrupt harddrive or SSD. Bu very hard top diagnose remotely without access to the system or a whole lot more information from your side.